# RestSharp and RestSharpSigned Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi, restsharp

Based on dependancies for multiple packages, I have to use both of these packages except using an API it calls a method that only exist in RestSharpSigned. Here is the trace and error for calling the method:

> {"Method not found: 'RestSharp.IRestRequest RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile(System.String, System.Action`1, System.String, System.String)'."}

Now the reason I know this is the issue is if I was to have only RestSharpSigned I can call the method without issue and then use the API intended without issues but if I was to have both RestSharp and RestSharpSigned I receive this error.

Any idea on a work around for this kind of situation?

Comment: What version of .NET Framework do you use?

Comment: The project is using .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .NET Framework 4.6.1, you should use the latest version of ResySharp (106.X at this moment).

Hence that from version 106, the signed `RestSharp` package already contains the signed assembly and the `RestSharp.Signed` package is not being released any more.

I would assume that you use the version 106 and at the same time use the older version from the Signed package, which causes the version conflict and incompatible signature issues.

You should stop using the Signed package and use the latest version of the `RestSharp` package instead, ensuring that you use one version of the package for all projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

While that does hopefully fix the problem of the two packages overlapping, the API requires restsharpsigned which leaves me with a compiler error of not meeting requirements if I only use RestSharp.